# Origin of the idiom "a few trombones short of a marching band"

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

I've heard the following idiom being used a few times recently but am unsure where it's come from:

> He's a few trombones short of a marching band.

I don't know exactly what it means and I can't find any reference to it but I'm sure that I've heard it on TV before. Any references/help would be appreciated.

Comment: There's [a lot of similar expressions](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Snowclones/few_X_short_of_a_Y) although I can't find any instances of this one. I don't suppose you remember where you heard it?

Comment: Related: [A few bricks short of a hod – what is the name for this type of saying?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/473369/a-few-bricks-short-of-a-hod-what-is-the-name-for-this-type-of-saying/473390#473390)

Answer (score 5):

> **A few X short of a Y**
> <sup>[*This Spoken English* - Namrata Palta · 2006](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Spoken_English/yhfCj3QVIFUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22few%20X%20short%20of%20a%22&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover)
>
> **Not possessing all of one's mental faculties; crazy, stupid**
>
> In these phrases, X is a common component of Y. Y represents full mental capacity, and the lack of a few X implies a lack of full mental capacity...</sup>
> . *a few fries short of a happy meal
>
> . a few sandwiches short of a picnic
>
> . two bricks short of a load
>
> . a few syllables short of a Haiku
>
> . a couple of cans short of a six-pack*

I suspect the basic trope has only been around (or at least, only *widespread*) for a few decades. The nearest *written* version of OP's example I could find was...

> [*a few trombones short of a **brass** band*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a%20few%20trombones%20short%20of%20a%20brass%20band%22)

...from a 1998 British stage review publication. But several of those "typical" examples suggest an Australian origin to me, and if this [NSW Public Schools *Millennium **Marching** Band*](https://artsunit.nsw.edu.au/program/nsw-public-schools-millennium-marching-band) is anything to go by, *marching* bands are still alive and kicking down under!

---

It's partly the fact that there are so *many* variations that makes me think it's "recent" (so still "novel"). Here's a bunch more from [*The Mammoth Book of Insults* - Geoff Tibballs · 2011](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Mammoth_Book_of_Insults/UUaeBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22he%27s%20a%20few%22%20%22short%20of%20a%22&pg=PT541&printsec=frontcover)...

> *He's a few trees short of an orchard
>
> He's a few clowns short of a circus
>
> He's a few peas short of a pod
>
> He's a few currants short of a fruit cake
>
> He's a few guppies short of an aquarium
>
> He's a few flowers short of an arrangement
>
> He's a few spokes short of a wheel
>
> He's several nuts short of a full pouch
>
> He's a few chapters short of a novel
>
> He's a few pancakes short of a stack
>
> He's a couplet short of a sonnet
>
> ...*

Comment: Good answer. William Muir, [_Police: Streetcorner Politicians_](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tbd0chRC7mEC&pg=PA73&dq=%22short+of+a+load%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0n7-1muuCAxXukO4BHRU8BjEQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22short%20of%20a%20load%22&f=false) (1979) uses (and explains) "three bricks short of a load," and...

Comment: ...an article in the November 1984 [_ABA Journal_](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22short+of+a+load%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=586549689&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1854%2Ccd_max%3A1992%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=OzpoZYvUN8WgkPIPj6eQuAM&ved=0ahUKEwjL3dKUmuuCAxVFEEQIHY8TBDcQ4dUDCAk&oq=%22short+of+a+load%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhEic2hvcnQgb2YgYSBsb2FkIjIFECEYqwJIoiVQ2ApYyxNwAHgAkAEAmAFUoAG0A6oBATa4AQzIAQD4AQGIBgE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) has "one brick short of a load," giving that wording a ten-year advantage over the earliest instance of 'X sandwich[es] short of picnic" that I could find.

Comment: I remember, some 60 years ago, my aunt describing some people as 'ninepence to the shilling' (the old British shilling being twelve old pence), so the idea isn't that recent.

Comment: @KateBunting: My grandmother used to say someone was ***right as ninepence*** - by which I think only meant *"not all there"*, as opposed to the homophobic ***queer as a nine-bob note*** which was also common back in the 60s. I've just discovered from [this pre-Internet 1890 Q&A](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Bye_gones/BNk4AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22right+as+ninepence%22&pg=PA492&printsec=frontcover) that it came from ***right as ninepins***.

Comment: Wikipedia says that **as right as ninepence** means 'Perfectly all right; in sound condition'.